# How to host /var/www/html/data/USER/files outside of docker

Tags: docker, nextcloud

What I want to do is host a directory on my machine in nextcloud.  Meaning, I have a folder on my machine /data/media that I would like to be the root folder when I open nextcloud.  Here is a snippet of my attempt in docker-compose

```
  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud:fpm-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
      - /data/media:/var/www/html/data/danrneal/files
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    env_file:
      - db.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
```

However when I docker-compose up and try to set an account I get the following error: `Cannot create or write into the data directory /var/www/html/data`.  Now I figure that the container doesn't have the right permissions on /data/media.... I need to have www-data own that folder.... but that doesn't work either because outside my container, www-data's uid is 33 and inside the container the uid is 82 so it's still mad.  Then I come across https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/pull/1278 which would allow me to specify a uid for the www-data user inside the container..... but that PR has been sitting there for over a year.  It's been approved and remains unmerged.

I guess my question is, is there an easier way to do what I am trying to accomplish?